# Video carousel slider

Tags: html, jquery, css, youtube, owl-carousel

I'm brand new to web developing so pardon me for my newbie question. I've been trying to create a video slider for 6 youtube videos of mine. I've searched a bunch of articles, forums and youtube videos on the topic but haven't been able to make it work.

I've found that creating an Owl carousel could work, but there isn't much information out there on creating an owl with video. From following the Owl documentation, this is what I've come up with so far:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".owl-carousel").owlCarousel();
});

$('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
  loop: true,
  margin: 10,
  nav: true,
  responsive: {
    0: {
      items: 1
    },
    600: {
      items: 3
    },
    1000: {
      items: 5
    }
  }
})
```

```css
.owl-carousel {
  display: flex;
}

.owl-video {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<section class="section-video">
  <div class="row">
    <h2>Video ads</h2>
    <p class="long-copy">Our video ad strategies are tested and proven to deliver. Take a look at some of our video ad examples down here.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="owl-carousel">
    <div class="owl-video">
      <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/4oMm2MGIphU" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

I'm not sure why the video isn't displaying, nothing is showing up. Any help/guidance would be greatly appreciated to put me on the right path!

Thank you,

Kim

Comment: Your embed is showing up for me (https://jsfiddle.net/jedisobe/60ha9kfo/1/). Also, shouldn't your HTML include multiple videos?

Comment: You may mind this example helpful: https://codepen.io/jamesharmer/pen/oNgRoBw